# Extract specific mimetype in shell

Tags: command-line, scripts

How can I extract from tar archive just text and executable files? Can I do this somehow with wildcards?

Comment: do the text files in your archive all have a `.txt` extension ? are the executable files binary or bash/python scripts?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to extract specific files using wildcards, but mimetype- or permission-based filtering can't be done without extracting the file first.

For filtering the files, these options are useful:

```
 --exclude=PATTERN
       exclude files, given as a PATTERN

 --null
       -T reads null-terminated names, disable -C

 -T, --files-from FILE
       get names to extract or create from FILE

 --wildcards
       use wildcards (default for exclusion)

 --wildcards-match-slash
       wildcards match '/' (default for exclusion)

 --no-wildcards-match-slash
       wildcards do not match '/'

 --no-wildcards
       verbatim string matching

 -X, --exclude-from FILE
       exclude patterns listed in FILE
```

For example:

```
$ tar tf foo.tar 
foo/
foo/c/
foo/c/file
foo/b/
foo/b/text
foo/a/
foo/a/executable
$ cat list.txt
*l*
$ tar tf ../foo.tar --wildcards --no-anchored -T list.txt
foo/c/file
foo/a/executable
```

So, only the files containing `l` were printed.

For mimetype or permissions, `tar` can [write the output file to an external command](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC87). `tar` provides information via environment variables about the filename, type, permissions, path, etc., which you can then use to detect the mimetype and permissions and save the file accordingly. But then you'd have to take care of ownership and permission yourself, and temporary storage of the file as well.